# while comparing two files by using Apache FileUtils.java

Tags: java

I am comparing two files by using Apache FileUtils.java in my JUnit . Both the files are exactly same while comparing via Beyond Compare , But the contentEquals(File file1, File file2) method of FileUtils.java returns false, because both the files length are different . can someone help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: How is it possible that the lengths are different and yet the content should be the same?

Comment: Please check that your diff tool is not ignoring white space characters in comparison. There might be extra blank lines or spaces between two files.

Comment: is it possible that encoding types are different?  ANSI vs UTF-8 with the BOM?

Answer (score 0):

If content lengths are different there might be special characters or different whitespaces.
Create your custom comparison ignoring white spaces and special characters